# How do I access only one of my touches in my touches began event

Tags: iphone, uitouch, multi-touch

I have:

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touches count] == 2) {
        //preforming actions                                                             
    }
```

What I want to do Is ask it inside of the `if`statement where the two touches are seperatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the touches:

```
if([touches count] == 2) {
    for(UITouch *aTouch in touches) {
        // Do something with each individual touch (e.g. find its location)
    }
}
```

**Edit**: if you want to, say, find the distance between the two touches, and you know there are exactly two, you can grab each separately then do some math. Example:

```
float distance;
if([touches count] == 2) {
    // Order touches so they're accessible separately
    NSMutableArray *touchesArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] 
                                     initWithCapacity:2] autorelease];
    for(UITouch *aTouch in touches) {
        [touchesArray addObject:aTouch];
    }
    UITouch *firstTouch = [touchesArray objectAtIndex:0];
    UITouch *secondTouch = [touchesArray objectAtIndex:1];

    // Do math
    CGPoint firstPoint = [firstTouch locationInView:[firstTouch view]];
    CGPoint secondPoint = [secondTouch locationInView:[secondTouch view]];
    distance = sqrtf((firstPoint.x - secondPoint.x) * 
                     (firstPoint.x - secondPoint.x) + 
                     (firstPoint.y - secondPoint.y) * 
                     (firstPoint.y - secondPoint.y));
}
```

Comment: Thank You That was what I needed to do but didn't understand

Answer (score -1):

Touches is already an array.  There's no need to copy them into another array -- just use [touches objectAtIndex:n] to access touch n.